# ConTeXt: Undefined control sequence \math_fenced_x_middle

Tags: context

This code example

```tex
\startformula
  E=\fenced[brace]{x\in\naturalnumbers \mid 0<x<\infty}
\stopformula
```

should produces

[image].

Unfortunately, with ConTeXt LMTX (2022.08.25) I only get the following error

```
Undefined control sequence \math_fenced_x_middle

<recently read>
    \math_fenced_x_middle
<macro> \p_mathclass
    \ifcase \c_math_fence_nesting \normalmid \else \middle \vert
    \fi
<argument>
    x\in \naturalnumbers \mid
    0<x<\infty
<macro> \math_fenced_fenced_indeed_adapt
    #1->\setfalse \c_math_fenced_sized \math_fenced_left #1
    \setfalse \c_math_fenced_sized \math_fenced_right \math_fenced_fenced_indeed_finish
<line 3.3>
      E=\fenced[brace]{x\in \naturalnumbers \mid 0<x<\infty}

1     \startTEXpage
2     \startformula
3 >>    E=\fenced[brace]{x\in \naturalnumbers \mid 0<x<\infty}
4     \stopformula
5     \stopTEXpage
6
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
\def'ed. You can just continue as I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\definemathfence[Set][brace][command=yes,middle=|]
```

and then

```
\startformula
  E=\Set{x\in\naturalnumbers \fence 0<x<\infty}
\stopformula
```

In fact, we tried different things out last week, and one can soon use setups.

```
\definemathfence[Set][brace][command=yes,middle=|,setups=math:fence:set]

\starttext
\startformula
\Set{a \suchthat b \where c \and d}
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

The `\suchthat` will use the middle class. The `\where` and `\and` will set commas,.hopefully with a nice spacing (can be changed in a setup). One could say that this is experimenting. Feedback is welcome.

(In fact, I wonder a bit what the `\mid` is supposed to be.)

Comment: Oh thanks ! Can you explain a bit further what you are trying to achieve here and what are the motivations behind?

Comment: We try to achieve natural and structired input and output. One can often read the constructions as in the example "The set of real x such that x>0 and x^2<a where a is prime". (Ok, not the best example, but on phone, so I will not type another one now.)